# Permission Denied while switching python virtual env in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I coded:

```
conda create -n pygame python=3
```

in terminal. And then I want to use *activate* to switch the env but it shows:

```
-bash: /anaconda3/bin/activate: Permission denied
```

What's the problem?
Here's the info of my anaconda:

```
 active environment : None
   user config file : /Users/zavierlyu/.condarc
     populated config files : /Users/zavierlyu/.condarc
      conda version : 4.5.9
conda-build version : 3.12.1
     python version : 2.7.15.final.0
   base environment : /anaconda3  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
      package cache : /anaconda3/pkgs
                      /Users/zavierlyu/.conda/pkgs
   envs directories : /anaconda3/envs
                      /Users/zavierlyu/.conda/envs
           platform : osx-64
         user-agent : conda/4.5.9 requests/2.19.1 CPython/2.7.15 Darwin/17.7.0 OSX/10.13.6
            UID:GID : 501:20
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

First time using stack overflow. Sorry for poor skills.

Comment: Can you run `ls -l /anaconda3/bin` and show the results? You may not have execute permissions

Comment: Have you tried activating the environment the way [the documentation suggests](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment)? My guess is that your user might not have access to the activate script, since conda is trying to control that.

Comment: @EdwardBrennanSo the official way is using `source activate myenv`? It works while using `source activate myenv`.

Comment: @C.Nivs It's a very long list. You need them all or just some info?